# hasOne with null-able in laravel not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, one-to-one

I have a customer table which has a field called 'policy_id', where policy_id points to policy table. It is a null-able field, ie. Some customers may not have a policy. 
I have a relationship code like this in Customer.php

```
public function policy() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Policy', "id", "policy_id");
}
```

But when I issue a search request I am getting error like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Policy]
```

If I modify the function like this:

```
public function policy() {
    if ($this->getAttribute('policy_id')) {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Policy', "id", "policy_id");
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error like this:

```
Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on null
```

Here is my search code:

```
    $c = new Customer();
    return Customer::doesntHave('policy')->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($req) {
        $query->orWhereHas('policy', function (Builder $query) use ($req) {
            $p = new Policy();
            $query->where($req->only($p->getFillable()))
                ->orWhereBetween("policy_period_from", [$req->policy_period_start_from, $req->policy_period_start_to])
                ->orWhereBetween("policy_period_to", [$req->policy_period_end_from, $req->policy_period_end_to])
                ->orWhereBetween("payment_date", [$req->payment_date_from, $req->payment_date_to]);
        });
    })->where($req->only($c->getFillable()))->get();
```

Am I missing something or are there any other ways to do this?

PS: While debugging the above search code is returning successfully, but the exception happening from somewhere inside Laravel after the prepareResponse call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the relevant code that is triggering the error?

Comment: I updated the code which causes the error.

Comment: Can you also provide the full stacktrace of the error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return $this->hasOne('App\ModelName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Change the order, put the foreign_key `policy_id` in front of `id`

In your Customer Model, you need to use **belongsTo** method:

```php
public function policy() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Policy', "policy_id", "id");
}
```

And In your Policy Model, use **hasOne**:

```php
public function customer() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer', "policy_id", "id");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my local key is policy_id. If I put the other way I will get error like this: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'policies.policy_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Harikrishnan so the policy_id is in your customers table, you need to use belongsTo in your Customer Model, I updated.

Comment: I tried that initially. But wasn't working. Still showing the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Policy] error.  The issue happens only with null values.

Comment: @Harikrishnan how do u call the relationship?

Comment: @Harikrishnan it's nothing wrong with nullable foreign_key, because if it is nullable, the relationship will be empty. so I think you are getting the result from the empty relationship. you need to post that code.

Comment: Sure. I updated the code in the question. doesntHave('policy') function is added after doing some research, just to check. But that also had no effect

Comment: @Harikrishnan  can you post the sql of your query? like `->toSql()` or `DB::getQueryLog()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you placed the wrong params.

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Policy', "FK", "PK");

public function policy() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Policy','policy_id', 'id');
}
```

And for `null` value of policy_id you can use `withDefault();`

```
public function policy() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Policy','policy_id', 'id')->withDefault([
        'name' => 'test'
    ]);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my local key is policy_id. If I put the other way I will get error like this: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'policies.policy_id' in 'where clause'. Also when I use withDefault I am getting the same error.

Comment: so this function is in Customer model, right? so from the customer model, you should use belongsTo relation. check the edited answer.

Comment: Did that too, but still same error. https://pastebin.com/Um9DCXNR has my table definitions.

Answer (score -1):

there's a number of problems there but can you perhaps specify the namespace and the class of both your models - Customer and Policy.
By default, the models you create with `php artisan make:model` will use the \App namespace e.g. \App\Customer and \App\Policy.
Just double check that.
Also, with regards to the relationship, if the Laravel conventions have been followed you could just:

In the Customer model

```php
public function policy() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Policy::class);
}
```

In the Policy model

```php
public function customer() {
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::class);
}
```

of if a multiple customers can be under one policy

```php
public function customers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

Good luck

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly in the OP case

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am creating the models under Models namespace for better organization. I was following the laravel guide where they use the string based syntax. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Hey @Harikrishnan - i think the relationship between the your models is a bit odd - can you perhaps share your migrations for both the customers and policies tables.

Comment: Ok - first of all - you should probably use laravel's migrations workflow check php aristan make:migration --create=table create_table... 2nd things check my edited post

Comment: I am following that. But I put sql as reference